# How can I create textView after the app launched

Tags: android, textview

Lets say my app imports a jokes txt file with 100 jokes.
Is there a method to fill each joke in textView in dynamic way so that if there 100 jokes it will create 100 textview if more it will create more.

Comment: I think a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) is way better than inserting hundrets of textViews...

Comment: why u dont use listView  with arrayadapter ?

Comment: If you're going to have that many items, you're better off using a ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to acomplish such a list. You can, for example, declare a `ScrollView` in your layout xml, and in this `ScrollView` add a `LinearLayout` with orientation vertical.

Then in code retrieve that layout and populate it like this.

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);

for (int i=0; i<nrJokes; i++ ){
        TextView text = new TextView(this);
        text.setText("Joke nr " + i);
        layout.addView(text);   
}
```

A cleaner but longer alternative would be to learn about ListView and adapters. You can find an awesome tutorial [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-listview-with-adapter-example.html)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Let the layout activity contain a LinearLayout (you may want to wrap it in a ScrollView)
2. Create a layout XML only containing a TextView
3. Get a hold of the LinearLayout using findViewById
4. Use LayoutInflater to create your TextView (styled as you like in the XML)
5. Add the TextView to the LinearLayout

Repeat step 4 and 5 for each joke.

This should get you going.

I have not posted code or examples as there are plenty of material on the subjects.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are new with android, Follwoing will be ideal solution for you.

1. Have listview implementation with a basic Adapter supplying you views for display.
2. When your download of data is complete, just change the data source for your adapter,
   e.g ArrayList or whatever your are using to store downloaded information, or append it.
3. Notify your listview about about data set being changed, so that listview will get refreshed with newly added items.

Hope it help.

Comment: thnx , yeah i'm new with android